# How do I solve ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in Django

Tags: python, django, valueerror

I have been working at a Django App. Basically, the function of the app is to take the input as a subject name from user using a Form, take the details of progressed activities of that subject of that specific user, and save each of that detail in a single variable. It involved 3 Models viz. User Model (Django's default) Subject Model and Detail Model, finally it will use those variables to which details are assigned, and calculate the performance using `fuzz_algo()`, and then return the result in the form of Messages to the Template.

Everything seems to be fine, but when I click the button Calculate in the template `users/performance_calculator.html`, it give this error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` at this statement `skype = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('skype_session_attendance')` in `views.py`

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import PerformanceCalculatorForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Subject, Detail
from .fuzzy_logic_algo import fuzz_algo

def performanceCalculator(request):
    skype = 0
    internal_course = 0
    prg_lab = 0
    mid_marks = 0
    final_marks = 0
    sub = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm(request.POST)

        if performance_form.is_valid():
            performance_form.save()

            sub = performance_form.cleaned_data.get('subject')
            skype = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('skype_session_attendance')
            internal_course = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('internal_course_marks')
            prg_lab = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('programming_lab_activity')
            mid_marks = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('mid_term_marks')
            final_marks = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('final_term_marks')

            result = fuzz_algo(skype, internal_course, prg_lab, mid_marks, final_marks)

            messages.success(request, result)

            return redirect('performance_calculator')
    else:
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm()

    context = {
        'performance_form': performance_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/performance_calculator.html', context)
```

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Subject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ({})'.format(self.subject, self.user.username)


class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.OneToOneField(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField()
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField()
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField()
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField()
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject, (self.user.username)} Details'

class Sub(models.Model):
    s = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile, Sub

class PerformanceCalculatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Sub
        fields = ['subject']
```

My performance_calculator.html (template):

```
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'esacp/main.css' %}">

        <title>Expert System for Assessing Programming Course Performance</title>
    </head>

    <body>        
        <main role="main" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% if messages %}
                        {% for message in messages %}
                            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                                {{ message }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if not request.user.is_superuser and not request.useris_staff %}
                        <div class="account-heading">
                            <h2>
                                Performance Calculator
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content-section">
                            <form method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <fieldset class="form-group">
                                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"></legend>
                                    {{ performance_form|crispy }}
                                </fieldset>
                                <div class="from-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Calculate</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>                
            </div>
        </main>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The full error I get at the statement `skype = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('skype_session_attendance')` is:

```
ValueError at /esacp/performance-calculator/
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/esacp/performance-calculator/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Exception Location: C:\environments\bsse_fyp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in build_filter, line 1247
Python Executable:  C:\environments\bsse_fyp\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\khubi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FYP\\test_phase',
 'C:\\Users\\khubi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\khubi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\khubi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\khubi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\environments\\bsse_fyp',
 'C:\\environments\\bsse_fyp\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 14 May 2020 07:12:19 +0000
```

I don't what has gone wrong and why it is showing this error. I read other threads here related to same issues, but their problem was they were using a 2D tuple instead of 1D tuple, or sometime dictionary or list issues, but I don't have any of that.

I have spent hours looking for the issue but I am unable to find one. Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the argument `user__username=User.username` supposed to do?

Comment: it is supposed to get the username of the current user (basically a student) using the system.

Comment: But what is does is to check if the `username` or `user` equals the **Field** `username` of the class `User` (the Field, not its value), which does not make sense.

Comment: actually it is being used as a filter, so yes it checks that to filter out the subjects which may include other user's subjects as well. The purpose is to calculate the performance of the one subject (whose name we take from user as an input) of the current user, based on his/her progress in the subject so fat (the Detail Model contains the progress).

Comment: I see, so, is there any better or correct way to use the current user's username for filtering the list of subjects?

Answer (score 0):

```
detail = Detail.objects.filter(...).first()
if detail:
    skype = detail.skype_session_attendance
```

You are calling `get` method of `QuerySet` instance. Which requires kwargs and returns one instance or throws error if result is None or there are more than one instance.
To get skype value you must first get instance.

Comment: and how would I get the first instance?

Comment: I added `.values().first()` in the skype statement but it is giving me this error now `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` on the same statement.